# Querying Column Definition for Data Length - SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am looking to generate a list of all the tables, columns, and datatypes for a database.

And this query will give me all information except for the length of the data types:

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName,
       c.name AS ColumnName,
       y.name AS DataType
FROM sys.tables AS t
    JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN sys.types AS y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'Tablename';
```

But for the columns with data types of `varchar` or `nvarchar`, I would like to also see the max limit for each.

For instance, if ColumnA is `varchar(100)` - where can I find the 100 limit in the database?  So far, I cannot find where that information is stored.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.columns` has a property called `max_length`:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    c.name AS ColumnName,
    c.max_length,
    y.name AS DataType
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
JOIN 
    sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.types AS y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE 
    t.name = 'Tablename';
```

See the [official MS documentation on `sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)   for more details

Comment: Thank you - I missed that completely.