# What is the safe way to query for the character length metadata for a SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get the character length of a column in SQL Server. Currently, I am using the `sys.columns` table. However, `max_length` is given in bytes. So if I have `nvarchar(100)`, that column will show 200.

1. Is there a column someplace else that will give me the character length of 100 instead of the byte length of 200?
2. If not, am I safe to just do the math and divide the byte length by two for `nvarchar` columns? Or are there some complicating factors (cultures, code pages, etc, etc,...) that would make that not a smart thing to do?

I found a similar question, though the answer strikes me as incomplete since the OP asks about both `varchar` and `nvarchar` and the answer doesn't point out that the column is in bytes. Sure, the column will have 100 in the case of `Column A varchar(100)` as stated, but not in the case of `Column B nvarchar(100)`: [Querying Column Definition for Data Length - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011471/querying-column-definition-for-data-length-sql-server).

Granted though, the question does specifically ask for data length in the title.

Comment: This is because nchar/nvarchar requires 2 bytes per character instead of one. You will also want to look at the system_type_id to isolate those that allow unicode characters. Then a case expression to divide by 2 when it is one of those types.

Comment: try sp_help tablename

Comment: When you say "character length" in your question are you under the misconception that `nvarchar(n)` gives you a character length of `n`?  [A common misconception is to think that NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n), the n defines the number of characters. But in NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n) the n defines the string length in byte-pairs (0-4,000). n never defines numbers of characters that can be stored.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)

Comment: @MartinSmith, arg, Yes, I did read this snippet in my search, but my brain snapped back to "character length". Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is safe to do this calculation.**

While it is true that multi-byte characters do exist, the length of a column specified by `varchar(n)` is always `n` bytes, and `nvarchar(n)` is always `n * 2` bytes. The number of real Unicode characters is actually irrelevant to how much you can insert.

For example, you [cannot insert](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64b8434b9ce8733dad8b2d9453246790) `N''` into `nvarchar(1)` even though it is a single Unicode character.

So `columns.max_length` will always tell you the `n` of `varchar(n)`, and  `columns.max_length / 2` will always tell you the `n` of `nvarchar(n)`, except that `-1` means `max`.

```sql
SELECT
  FullType = CASE
      WHEN typ.name = 'nvarchar'
        THEN CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN '(max)' ELSE CONCAT(typ.name, '(', c.max_length / 2, ')') END
      WHEN typ.name = 'varchar' OR typ.name = 'varbinary'
        THEN CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN '(max)' ELSE CONCAT(typ.name, '(', c.max_length, ')') END
      -- etc
      END
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.types typ ON typ.user_type_id = c.system_type_id  -- join the underlying type to the real type ID, in case of user alias types
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a 100% safe way of doing this.

The max lengths are all ultimately defined in bytes (though for `nvarchar` by doubling the declared length) and the relationship between byte and character is not fixed.

- For `varchar` columns there has existed for a long time double byte collations where a character can consume `1` or `2` bytes.
- SQL Server 2012 added `SC` (Supplementary Character) collations that support UTF-16. In these collations a single `nvarchar` character may take 2 or 4 bytes.
- Even without those collations there is nothing stopping someone inserting values such as `N''` - which are a single character to the end user even though `LEN(N'')` returns `2`
- SQL Server 2019 introduced `UTF-8` collations - meaning a `varchar` character can consume anywhere between `1` to `4` bytes

Comment: You can't insert a double-byte character into `varchar(1)` and equally cannot insert four-byte characters into `nvarchar(1)` see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64b8434b9ce8733dad8b2d9453246790 so most of this is a moot point: `nvarchar(SomeLength)` *always* allows up to `SomeLength * 2` bytes, which is the value in `max_length`. I don't think collation makes a difference here either in that respect, it only governs what characters you can put in, and how they are sorted

Comment: Seems that you are interpreting the request as being to find the value that the documentation carefully calls ["byte-pairs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) rather than "character length" in which case yes, of course, dividing by two will give you the number of pairs. I was thinking in terms of it being about the largest size string that would be guaranteed to fit into the column.

Comment: Quite right, that is how I interpret the question. In other words: it seems to me OP just wants to know if they can safely determine the `n` part of `nvarchar(n)`. And you are interpreting it as how many textual characters can they fit, which depends on what values you put into it (and therefore irrelevant to `sys.columns`). Let's see what OP says, it may be they don't know themselves what they're asking, often happens :-)

Comment: Thanks. I think the crux of my question was since I define these columns as nvarchar(n) in CREATE TABLE. How do I safely get my n back out? n could be anything: characters, byte pairs, or pickles, I just want my definition back. I find it curious that if I right click in SSMS -> Script Table As... -> CREATE To... It will script it correctly, so n must be in a table somewhere, or so I was thinking. And if there is not a 100% safe way to do this myself, how is the system doing it?

Comment: @MikeBundy to get the value of n just divide it by 2 and special case max. But your question was about character length which is a different question than that.